# MySQL subquery inside ORDER BY field. (without Inner Join)

Tags: php, mysql

*There are many question related to this but all have same answer of using inner join, which is (I think) not possible here. (say me if I am wrong)*

What I am doing now is calling two different mysql query to get result. It works perfectly.

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM `meta` WHERE `metakey` = 'category_order'");
$order = $db->fetch_assoc()['metavalue'];  
/*$order = 2,1,12,11,10*/

$db->query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `parent` = '0' ORDER BY field(ID, $order)");           
$cats = $db->fetch();
```

Now to reduce number of queries I tried something like,

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `parent` = '0' ORDER BY field(ID, (SELECT 'metavalue' FROM `meta` WHERE `metakey` = 'category_order'))");
```

It doesn't show any error, but it gives me wrong output. Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT**

categories table's structure,

```
_________________
| ID  | name    |
-----------------
| 1   | A       |
| 2   | B       |
| 11  | C       |
| 12  | D       |
| 10  | E       |
-----------------
```

meta table's structure,

```
______________________________________
| ID | metakey        | metavalue    |
--------------------------------------
| 1  | category_order | 2,1,12,11,10 |
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really see a way to do it directly using ORDER BY FIELD.

However I wonder if you could do a JOIN against the meta table and then ORDER BY a FIND_IN_SET.

Not tested this, but hopefully will give you the idea:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM `categories` 
INNER JOIN meta ON metakey = 'category_order' AND FIND_IN_SET(categories.ID,metavalue)
WHERE `parent` = '0' 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(categories.ID,metavalue)
```

Possibly the FIND_IN_SET on the JOIN isn't necessary

Comment: Awesome !!! It's the pixel perfect answer, working like charm. Thanks @Kickstart.

Answer (score 1):

try using `GROUP_CONCAT` and don;t wrap column `metavalue` with single quote as it converts it to string literal.

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `parent` = '0' ORDER BY field(ID, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`metavalue`) FROM `meta WHERE `metakey` = 'category_order'))");
```

Comment: It doesn't show any error but gives wrong output. Output should be in order "2,1,12,11,10", but it gives "1,10,11,12,2"