# MySQL Order a SELECT based on other SELECT

Tags: mysql

I've got these two selects:

```
SELECT ent_user, ent_video_type, count(*) AS total 
FROM entry WHERE ent_user='1' 
GROUP BY ent_video_tipo 
ORDER BY total DESC

ent_user|ent_video_type|total
    1   |       1      |  3
    1   |       3      |  2
    1   |       4      |  1
```

And I've got this other select:

```
SELECT * FROM meta

met_id|met_name|user_id|met_type
   10 |  bla   |   2   |    1
   11 | blabla |   4   |    2
   12 |  foo   |   1   |    3
   13 | blafoo |   3   |    4
   14 | foofoo |   5   |    4
```

How can I order the last select so it is like this:

```
met_id|met_name|user_id|met_type
   10 |  bla   |   2   |    1
   12 |  foo   |   1   |    3
   13 | blafoo |   3   |    4
   14 | foofoo |   5   |    4
   11 | blabla |   4   |    2
```

I want to order the last select by `met_type`depending on the first select. I want to make `ent_video_type`=`met_type` so I can order the last select by `met_type`.

How can I do that ?

I want to order the `met_type` column by the order of the column `ent_video_type`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL subquery inside ORDER BY field. (without Inner Join)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362215/mysql-subquery-inside-order-by-field-without-inner-join)

Comment: I didn't said I couldn't use `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Who did? There are multiple approaches that can help you.

Comment: I know I can do this with INNER JOIN, I just don't remember how :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in the first "Select" fields, you are not allowed to use "ent_user". It is neither mentioned in the group by field nor in an aggregate function. So I wonder how you got answer running it.

Anyway, based on the same code, I have added "ent_user" to the "group by" clause and have wrote this solution:

I added extraField just for ordering.

```
Select meta.*, 1 as extraField 
    From meta
        inner join (
            SELECT ent_user, ent_video_type, count(*) AS total 
                FROM entry WHERE ent_user='1' 
                GROUP BY ent_user, ent_video_tipe
            ) as t1 on meta.met_type = t1.ent_video_type
union all
Select *, 2 
    From meta
    Where met_type not in (
            SELECT distinct ent_video_type
                FROM entry WHERE ent_user='1' 
        ) 
Order by extraField, met_type
```

Or you can use this one if you don't want extraField to be shown:

```
Select met_id, met_name, user_id, met_type
    From (
        Select meta.*, 1 as extraField 
            From meta
                inner join (
                    SELECT ent_user, ent_video_type, count(*) AS total 
                        FROM entry WHERE ent_user='1' 
                        GROUP BY ent_user, ent_video_tipe
                    ) as t1 on meta.met_type = t1.ent_video_type
        union all
        Select *, 2 
            From meta
            Where met_type not in (
                    SELECT distinct ent_video_type
                        FROM entry WHERE ent_user='1' 
                ) 
        ) as t1
    Order by extraField, met_type
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin gave me this error, `#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT met_id, met_name, user_id, met_type, ent_user, ent_video_type, count(*) AS total  
FROM meta

LEFT JOIN entry ON ent_video_type = met_type

WHERE ent_user='1' 

GROUP BY ent_video_type 

ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: It doesn't give anything :/

Comment: Both my and @vikramjain's solution work perfect: the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92cfb/2/0) can be seen here

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.ent_user, E.ent_video_type, count(*) AS total 
FROM entry E
left outer join meta M on E.ent_video_type=M.met_type
WHERE E.ent_user='1' 
GROUP BY E.ent_video_type 
ORDER By total DESC
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) AS total 
FROM entry E
left outer join meta M on E.ent_video_type=M.m`

Comment: Just remove M.* and put only * in sql query as per updated output]